# Helm/ YAML indentation issue

Tags: yaml, helm

I am etting weird YAML indentation with some conditional stuff, effectively I'm doing:

```
resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 10 }}
{{- if .Values.filebeat.enabled -}}
      - name: elastic-logger
```

But the final line is indented by 10, not 8 as it should be. in fact I can indent it by 0, 10, 100 - but it's always indented 10. any ideas? (edited)
`.Values.resources` is for one container, and if `filebeat.enabled` then I'm adding another container to the array
output:

```
 resources:
 {}
    - name: elastic-logger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `-}}` is a special syntax which says 'eat up any following whitespace'.  Removing the `-` fixed this.

I get a blank line, but don't really care, considering!